# Ruby Mechanize gem, restore Mechanize::Page object from local html copy

Tags: ruby, rubygems, copy, mechanize, local

here is code that I have:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://google.com'
page.save 'google_index.htm'
```

How can I restore that `google_index.htm` to `Mechanize::Page` object and continue working with that page, eg. submit, parse, etc?

I've tried to do `YAML::dump()` or `Marshal::dump()`, but it seems to be impossible:

```
irb(main):024:0> page.class
=> Mechanize::Page
```

then:

```
irb(main):013:0> YAML::dump(page) 
TypeError: can't dump anonymous class Class
```

and:

```
irb(main):023:0> Marshal::dump(page)
TypeError: no marshal_dump is defined for class Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

Comment: I don't think you are using the #save method the way it is intended to be used. From http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/File.html#method-c-new, it seems to be intended for saving files in known formats (.jpg, .pdf, etc) not for marshaling mechanize objects. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I have site with authorization and I need to use this form, before I can use this form I need to go through some urls, submit auth form, click some links and then finally I get to the form I need to submit. To omit all of this boring steps I want to save this form and site cookies to be able to submit it from my local machine.

Comment: So you only want to save it to your machine one time?  If so, I think I might suggest that you save the form manually or by using curl or wget and then reading it in using the method I show below.  The method I used below doesn't work very well for the google_index.htm file because "page.save" includes the Mechanize cruft.

Comment: Yes, I want to save it to my local machine and then submit this saved form with Mechanize. I don't need to parse it with nokogiri. I need to have `Mechanize::Page` object from this locally saved form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just restore the cookies:

```
agent.cookie_jar.save_as('cookies')
agent.cookie_jar.load('cookies')
```

There's a good chance that your session will be expired though.

Comment: Yes, I'm saving cookies, but I wanted to save that page instance to be able not to fetch it again. But that wasn't real, so now I am saving cookies and then loading it before requesting page I need. 

So I consider your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    f = File.open("google_index.htm")
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
    # do stuff with f
```